# Getting "Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message """ from Mail component in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I am stumped with this issue I am having with Laravel. I have a mailable setup and am trying to test out sending as I create a new model record. But for the life of me, no matter what I try or change I always get the above error.

I can assure you that I do have the credentials and server/port identifications correct as I tried using them to setup an email client on my laptop. So I know these are working bits of information.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
|            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'myHOST'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myEMAIL'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'MyCMX'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('myEMAIL'),

'password' => env('myPASSWORD'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Has anyone come up with a problem like this?

Comment: have you enabled 2 step verification

Comment: I was just about to edit the question but no I haven’t and that’s only because this email and host aren’t from gmail.

Comment: just a check can you change the encryption from tls to ssl and do php artisan config:cache and php artisan config:clear

Comment: Hi - This is what I get now: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown

Comment: However, even though I don't change a thing, on clearing the cache and such, I get this error persisting: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Comment: This error i am encountering for the first time, i'll do a bit research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160158/discussion-between-rohit-shah-and-matthew).